# poetry [EnvCommandError] Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, python-poetry, toml

I have a `pyproject.toml` file that was created using poetry, and I'm trying to run the command `poetry install` in this directory to create  a `poetry.lock` file. However, when I run poetry install, I get the following error:

```
  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\my-app-name-kS94etse-py3.8\Scripts\python.exe - 
  errored with the following return code 3, and output:
      Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
        File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\abc.py", line 106
          print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                            ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      input was : import sys
```

This error seems pretty in depth but I dont understand why poetry thinks `import sys` is invalid syntax or even where that's being called to create an issue. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67169273/12060361

1. Download a new, non-broken version of Python (the same version defined in your `pyproject.toml` file to use): https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/
2. Navigate to the virtual env folder poetry says the error is coming from: `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\my-app-name-kS94etse-py3.8\Scripts\python.exe`
3. Replace the `python.exe` currently in that folder with the new one you just downloaded