# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, virtualenv, sys, python-poetry

I have a `pyproject.toml` file that was created using poetry, and I'm trying to run the command `poetry install` in this directory to create  a `poetry.lock` file. However, when I run poetry install, I get the following error:

```
  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\my-app-name-kS94etse-py3.8\Scripts\python.exe - 
  errored with the following return code 3, and output:
      Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
        File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\abc.py", line 106
          print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                            ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      input was : import sys
```

This error seems pretty in depth but I dont understand why poetry thinks `import sys` is invalid syntax. I went to the directory it's throwing the error at, `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\my-app-name-kS94etse-py3.8\Scripts\python.exe` and even just trying to run the `python.exe` there I get something similar:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "c:\users\myName\anaconda3\lib\abc.py", line 106
    print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up resolving my own issue. For some reason my virtual environment created by poetry is copying/downloading a broken version of Python, which as I said in my initial question, it seemed the `python.exe` alone was what is throwing the fatal error.

With that, I resolved my issue by:

1. Downloading a new, non-broken version of Python (the same version that I defined in my `pyproject.toml` file to use): https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/
2. Navigated to the virtual env folder poetry told me the error was coming from: `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\my-app-name-kS94etse-py3.8\Scripts\python.exe`
3. Replaced the `python.exe` currently in that folder with the new one I just downloaded

I'm sure long-run I'll need to find why this is occurring, but this is a quick fix for anyone else running into this issue. Happy poetry-ing!